# How do I find the first two consecutive elements in my array of numbers?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Using Ruby 2.4, I have an array of unique, ordered numbers, for example

```
[1, 7, 8, 12, 14, 15]
```

How do I find the first two elements whose difference is 1?  For example, the above array the answer to that is "7" and "8".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `each_cons` and `find` to get the first element from the array of pairs where the second element less the first one is equal to 1:

```
p [1, 7, 8, 12, 14, 15].each_cons(2).find { |a, b| b - a == 1 }
# => [7, 8]
```

Comment: If you want the first match, use `find { ... }` instead of `select { ... }[0]`

Answer (score 4):

Here are three more ways.

**#1**

```
def first_adjacent_pair(arr)
  (arr.size-2).times { |i| return arr[i, 2] if arr[i+1] == arr[i].next }
  nil
end

first_adjacent_pair [1, 7, 8, 12, 14, 15] #=> [7,8]
first_adjacent_pair [1, 7, 5, 12, 14, 16] #=> nil
```

**#2**

```
def first_adjacent_pair(arr)
  enum = arr.to_enum # or arr.each
  loop do
    curr = enum.next
    nxt = enum.peek
    return [curr, nxt] if nxt == curr.next
  end
  nil
end
```

`enum.peek` raises a `StopIteration` exception when the enumerator `enum` has generated its last element with the preceding `enum.next`. The exception is handled by [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) by breaking out of the loop, after which `nil` is returned. See also [Object#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum), [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek).

**#3**

```
def first_adjacent_pair(arr)
  a = [nil, arr.first] 
  arr.each do |n|
    a.rotate!
    a[1] = n
    return a if a[1] == a[0] + 1
  end
  nil
end
```

See [Array#rotate!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate-21).

Comment: Also `arr[idx-1, 2]` could be more concise for slicing out the answer here.

Comment: Another note is that `idx` will either be a value from the array or `nil`, so `idx && arr[idx-1,2]` is another option. It side-steps a ternary, but might be equally confusing. Tough call.

Comment: @tadman, yes, I considered that (as well as what would now be `arr[idx-1,2] unless idx.nil?`), but thought the ternary would be clearer.

Comment: Note that in #1, you already have the answer in the loop, i.e. `arr[i-1]` and `arr[i]`. Returning `i` in order to fetch the same values via `arr[i-1, 2]` seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example

```
   X = [1, 7, 8, 12, 14, 15]

   X.each_with_index do |item, index|
    if index < X.count - 1
     if (X[index+1]-X[index] == 1) 
      puts item
     end
   end
  end
```

Comment: Could be simpler, though.

Comment: JFYI, it's very un-rubyish to name your variables in Pascal case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate method provided for educational purposes:

```
arr = [1, 7, 8, 12, 14, 15]

arr.each_cons(2).map {|v|v.reduce(:-)}.index(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
a.each_with_index { |e, i| break [ e, a[i.next] ] if a[i.next] == e.next } 
#=> [7, 8]
```

Unlike `chunk` or `each_cons` this doesn't create an array of arrays. It also breaks as soon as a pair is found.

---

#### Benchmarks

```
require 'fruity'

arr = ((1...1000)).to_a.reverse + [1,2]

def first_adjacent_pair(arr)
  idx = arr.each_index.drop(1).find { |i| (arr[i-1]-arr[i]).abs == 1 }
  idx ? arr[idx-1, 2] : nil
end

def first_adjacent_pair2(arr)
  enum = arr.to_enum
  loop do
    curr = enum.next
    nxt = enum.peek
    return [curr, nxt] if (curr-nxt).abs == 1
  end
  nil
end

compare do
  iceツ  { ar = arr.dup; ar.each_with_index { |e, i| break [ e, ar[i.next] ] if ar[i.next] == e.next }  }
  cary   { ar = arr.dup; first_adjacent_pair(ar) }
  cary2  { ar = arr.dup; first_adjacent_pair2(ar) }  
  seb    { ar = arr.dup; ar.each_cons(2).find{|a,b| b-a == 1} }
end

#Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 1 second.
#cary2 is faster than cary by 3x ± 0.1
#cary is faster than iceツ by 3x ± 0.1 (results differ: [999, 998] vs [1, 2])
#iceツ is faster than seb by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
```