# Detect if the following value in array is a duplicate

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to make a method which detects if the following value in an array is a duplicate, and deletes it if so. It should work for both strings and integers.

For example, given the Array:

```
arr = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D", "D"]
```

Return:

```
arr = ["A", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D"]
```

I tried creating an empty Array `a`, and shovelling the values in, providing the following value was not equal to the current one. I attempted this like so:

```
arr.each do |x|
  following_value = arr.index(x) + 1
  a << x unless x == arr[following_value]
end
```

Unfortunately, instead of shovelling one of the duplicate values into the array, it shovelled neither.

```
arr = ["A", "C", "c", "A"]
```

Can anybody help? Bonus points for telling me exactly what went wrong with my method.

Thanks!

Comment: I there a reason why you don't want to use `["A", "B", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D", "D"].uniq`?

Comment: @katafrakt, it will remove `A`, as I understand OP wants to take element if next isn't equal to it

Comment: @katafrakt: The question is  a bit unclear, but it looks like the OP only wants to compact *consecutive* runs of equal elements.

Comment: Yes, because I don't wish to return only the unique values. I only want the element to be deleted if it is equal to the previous element. In the example you have quoted, I wish to retain both entries equal to "A".

Comment: Your method is not working because `arr.index(x)` will always return the index of the first matching element. Please note my answer for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First at all, here is simpler solution:

```
> arr.delete_if.with_index { |e, ind| e == arr[ind+1] }
#=> ["A", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D"]
```

But, this solution will mutate `arr`.
Here are one-line solutions without mutates:

```
arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(e, ind), res| res << e if e != arr[ind+1] }
arr.each_with_object([]) { |e, res| res << e if res.last != e }
```

Your problem in this line: `a << x unless x == arr[following_value]`
You say: put this `element` into `result` if `next element` isn't equal to it. So, instead, you can say something like: *put this element to result if the last element of the result isn't equal to it*:

```
arr.each do |x|
  a << x unless a.last == x
end
```

Comment: That solution is perfect, thank you Alex. I forgot all about `with_index`.

I don't want to sound daft, but I'm still not 100% certain why my example didn't work.

What I thought would happen is: 

    _A != B, so shovel into a;_
    _B == B, so don't shovel into a;_
   _B != C, so shovel into a._

Do you see what I mean? 

And thanks again, all your examples are super useful. :)

Comment: [Array#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) is the same as `Array#reject!`, which provides a clue to how your initial method can be changed to avoid mutating `arr`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would use [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select), so you could do something like:

```
a = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D", "D"]

# without mutation
b = a.select.with_index { |e, i| a[i+1] != e }
a #=> ["A", "B", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D", "D"]
b #=> ["A", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D"]

# with mutation
a.select!.with_index { |e, i| a[i+1] != e }
a #=> ["A", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D"]
```

BTW your method is not working because `arr.index(x)` [returns index of first object for which block is true](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/index):

```
arr = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D", "D"]
arr.each do |x|
  puts "#{x} has index #{arr.index(x)}"
end
A has index 0
B has index 1
B has index 1 # you were expecting 2
C has index 3
c has index 4
A has index 0 # you were expecting 5
D has index 6
D has index 6 # you were expecting 7
```

Comment: Gabriel, both of your solutions are also great. Additionally, thank you so much for explaining why my method wasn't working! It was driving me crazy haha. I really appreciate the explanation. +1

Comment: about `arr.index(x)` - it's wrong, as you can see, OP define `following_value` as `arr.index(x) + 1` and than: `x == arr[following_value]` :)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko `arr.index(x)` for the first `"B"` is `1` so `following_value` is `2` (`1 + 1`). And `arr.index(x)` for the second `"B"` is also `1` so `following_value` is `2` (`1 + 1`) too. As I said `arr.index(x)` returns index of first object for which block is true, and therefore you can't use this method in this case - that's what went wrong with OP method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a succinct alternative:

```
arr = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D", "D"]

arr.chunk(&:itself).map(&:first)
# => ["A", "B", "C", "c", "A", "D"]
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/JGV4/1

Answer (score 1):

Derived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44788219/5101493) answer by [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970,):

```
def remove_consecs ar
  enum = ar.each
  loop.with_object([]) do |_, arr|
    curr = enum.next
    nxt = arr.last || enum.peek
    arr << curr if curr != nxt
  end
end

remove_consecs ["A", "B", "B", 'D', "C", "c", "A", "D", "D"]
#=> ["A", "B", "D", "C", "c", "A", "D"]
```