# How do I figure out if my array has two consecutive elements that match a regular expression?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4.  If I have an array of strings, how do I figure out if there are two consecutive strings that match a regular expression?

For instance, I have:

```
["1234", "aa", "cc33", "44"]
```

I want to see if there are two consecutive elements that begin with letters (in the above case, that condition is `true`, `"aa"` and `"cc33"`).  But in the below case it would be `false`:

```
["bb", "55", "mm", "77"]
```

This

```
my_arr.select { |str| str =~ /^\p{L}/ }
```

tells me how many strings begin with letters, but it doesn't tell me if I have two consecutive elements that begin with letters.

How do I figure that out?

Comment: something like `arr.each_cons(2).any? {|a,b| a[/\A[a-z]/i] && b[/\A[a-z]/i]}`

Comment: If you want something faster than `each_cons` look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44787236/5101493, "your question in fact!") which has some alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your same regex, you could do this:

```
my_arr.each_cons(2).any? { |pair| pair.all? { |elem| elem =~ /^\p{L}/ } }
```

Check [this snippet](https://repl.it/JJ1t).

Answer (score 0):

I understand you wish to determine if two consecutive elements of an array match a given regular expression. To do that efficiently we would like check as few elements (strings) as possible for matches. In particular, we don't want to necessarily check all elements of the array or check individual elements twice. Here is one way to do that.

```
arr = ["1234", "aa", "cc33", "44"]
r = /\A[[:alpha:]]{2}/

a = [false, false]
arr.any? do |s| 
   a[0] = s.match?(r)
   a.rotate! == [true, true]
end
   #=> true
```

[String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) made its debut in Ruby v2.4. For earlier versions one could write `!!(s =~ r)`. The inner exclamation mark convert a truthy value to `false` and a falsy value to `true`; the outer exclamation mark flips that result from `true` to `false` and vice-versa.